# Android Studio: Gradle Error "cannot start process command 'ndk-build.cmd'"

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library from Github. I think I added the library project correctly, but when I try to build Gradle, I get the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':libs:tess-two-master:tess-two:ndkBuild'.
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''

**build.gradle (tess-two):**

```
 // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    workingDir = file("${android.sdkDirectory}/ndk-bundle")
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('.').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
        } else {
            commandLine './ndk-build', '-C', file('.').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
        }
}
```

**file structure:**

```
AppName/libs/tess-two-master/tess-two

build   src                    
jni     ...         
res     build.gradle
```

**settings.gradle (app)**

```
include ':app'
include ':libs:tess-two-master:tess-two'
```

I tried going through the files line by line, but I can't find anything wrong. My experience with Gradle is almost nil.

Comment: You should install and set ndk first.

Comment: Open you project structure and you will see ndk.